# Alterar value de input Number dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, html

Bom dia pessoal! Sou novo nisso, quero que o valor do meu input some ou subtraia com ao clicar nos botões. Mas não está funcionando... E quando eu faço a alteração manualmente e clico em algum dos botões, o valor passa a ser o default que é 8.

```js
function addAtribute(index) {
  if (document.getElementById(index).value < 20) {
    document.getElementById(index).value = Number(document.getElementById(index).value) + 1;
  }
}

function subAtribute(index) {
  if (document.getElementById(index).value > 9) {
    document.getElementById(index).value = Number(document.getElementById(index).value) - 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Status</td>
      <td>Valor</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>exemplo</td>
      <td><button onclick="subAtribute('exemplo')" ;><img src="img/icons/menos.png"></button>
        <input type="number" name="Exemplo" id="exemplo" value="8" min="8" max="20">
        <button onclick="addAtribute('exemplo')" ;><img src="img/icons/mais.png"></button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Achei a resposta! Era só incluir o tipo do botão no botão `type="button`" para que ele não desse reload na página.